# Controller 404 Page Not Found using Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, controller

I created this files... based on TutsPlus Premium Magento Tutorial 
I am using the latest Magento right now.

file path

**\app\code\local\TutsPlus\Demo\etc**

this is the codes

`config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Model</class>
            </demo>
        </models>

        <blocks>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Block</class>
            </demo>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Helper</class>
            </demo>
        </helpers>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <tutsplus_demo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TutsPlus_Demo</module>
                    <frontName>demo</frontName>
                </args>
            </tutsplus_demo>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

---

**app\code\local\TutsPlus\Demo\controllers**

this is the codes

`IndexController.php`

```
<?php

class TutsPlus_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function sayHelloAction() {
        echo "Hello Junar";
    }

}
```

The Output must be: Hello Junar but it gives me 404 Page Not Found

Comment: please help me, i need to learned this for me to continue to the next chapter

Comment: Which tutorial did u follow.? can u share the link.? you have not created the layout xml file for your module

Comment: FrontName/controller/actionName
Eg:http://localhost:2020/clover/index.php/demo/index/sayHello

Comment: sir this is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8du-M0WdQu0&list=PLrbYkjuliSBKd9Nf10Pt4Ii_kwWyq-Oxc

Comment: am talking about the link of the tutorial you followed

Comment: can you send the url please ??

Comment: I already post the link sir @Ramki

Comment: i mean which url you run you got an 404 error ?

Comment: Check this https://gordonlesti.com/tutorialmagento2-hello-world/

Comment: @Manashvibirla not this one in your localhost or sever run the file means you got an error 404 error i'm asking that url man ?

Comment: oh that site almost the same with tutsplus tutorial @Manashvibirla, I guess he copied it but I give a try

Comment: Have you created another TutsPlus_Demo.xml file and put it under the etc\modules folder 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <TutsPlus_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TutsPlus_Demo>
    </modules>    
</config>

Comment: please rename IndexController.php instead of IndexController.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the file to enable your module in

app/etc/modules/TutsPlus_Demo.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TutsPlus_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TutsPlus_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**you have to include your module first to make your module works.**

you can call it by request this url.

```
http://yourdomain/yourmagento/demo/index/sayHello
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Model</class>
            </demo>
        </models>

        <blocks>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Block</class>
            </demo>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Helper</class>
            </demo>
        </helpers>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <demo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TutsPlus_Demo</module>
                    <frontName>demo</frontName>
                </args>
            </demo>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dare to assume that supposing you got a typo in your question, the problem is in the name of your file controller:

IndexController.xml should be ---->  IndexController.php

Comment: yah i see it, I will change the question but the problem is now solved, thanks for your answer